# Looking for a short cartoon from the 70s: "The Jelly Doughnut Vampire"

Tags: story-identification, tv

The title was "The Jelly Doughnut Vampire", and it was a 20 minute (approx.) short on PBS.  It was a Frankenstein/Dracula parody based around baked monsters.  One line was "And when we woke up, all the doughnuts had two holes in them, and the jelly was all sucked out!"  Would like to see this short again.

I have contacted the TV stations that I saw it on, but they were unable to assist.

Comment: Hey! Don't be mean to jelly doughnuts!!!

Comment: Wow, I never thought there would be a vampire who appreciated making holes of different types!

Comment: I want to see this again too.  After James posted the title and director below, I searched online hoping to find a copy.  Someone posted a version that played on German television.  It runs only 6 minutes (the original is 9.5 minutes) so it is abridged, and it has been dubbed into German.  I know a little German, but I think you might enjoy it even if you can't understand a word of it.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wgIOq3DF94c

Comment: Adding comment from deleted answer that contact info can be found at https://web.archive.org/web/20160313225130/http://www.crunchbirdstudios.com/Videos.htm, and a copy of the film was acquired through that contact info.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is an obscure but very cute animated short titled [The Mad Baker](https://www.bcdb.com/cartoon/57943-Mad-Baker). I have not seen it since the mid-1970s and details are sketchy in my mind (and there is not a lot about it online) but the line about the the jelly being sucked out if the jelly donuts is there. Another bit of dialog you may remember:

> “Strange little chap; he hardly seems human.”

Response:

> He’s not; I baked him

The description from the link above matches what you remember:

> In this parody of classic Frankenstein and Dracula films, a vampire-like "mad baker" lives in a spooky castle. His main creation is a monstrous chocolate cake which comes to life and eats its creator.

Around 20 years ago I contacted the director to see if this film was available on any media other than celluloid film. At the time, he was not willing to risk it going online. I too would love to see it again.

Comment: The director, Fred Petok, passed away in 2010. Apparently his some sold his films on video, but the link to buy them is now long dead.

Comment: you can add something from here: https://web.archive.org/web/20160313225130/http://www.crunchbirdstudios.com/Videos.htm When you click on "Contact us", there's a name and a phone number. > Questions, comments, orders:. Call 301-947-2927. Questions, comments:. E-mail - Crunch Bird Studios - fpetok@comcast.net Long live the wayback machine! Also mentioned here:
https://cartoonresearch.com/index.php/cartoons-considered-for-an-academy-award-1972/

Comment: @MichaelaP., I have emailed that address, will post if I hear anything

Comment: @MichaelaP., I am reluctant to do that without confirming the number and email are still valid and useable for this purpose, which I have neither time nor inclination to do at present.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod, Appreciate the title and director info as I have wanted to see this again too.  Found an abridged 6 minute version dubbed into German on youtube.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wgIOq3DF94c

Comment: Answering here, so as to keep it from being lost as a comment. Used the Wayback to get the contact address (will not include here, as I'm not sure if it's proper to doing so, but the contact said the email could be released), and was able to order a DVD of the cartoon. It arrived yesterday. It was $35 for a DVD-R (plus shipping), which is a bit high for a single cartoon, but I'm glad I was able to get it. Thank all for the help!

Comment: @Zenzizenzizenzic So - does it live up to your memories?

Comment: There was some nostalgia shining, but for the most part, yes it did.  :)  Watched it again with my father yesterday.